# A simple question on conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ two i.i.d having an uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. Then what is the conditional expectation, $\mathbb{E}[x / y\ |\ x < y]$.

It seems to me, this should be:

$\int_{\{x < y\}}{x/y\ dP(\cdot\ |\ x <y)} = (1 /\mathbb{P}[x < y])\int_0^1\int_0^y{x/y\ dx dy}$. Is this correct? Where $\mathbb{P}[x < y]$ is the probability that $x < y$ which is 1/2.

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: one-word answer should be a comment, fine. I'm new here, first anyone told me that. When I _answer_ a question and he says my answer doesn't answer the question he should either explain or retract. Saying an answer doesn't answer the question (when it does) is insulting. So instead of retracting we delete the thing. Not right. Lack of integrity.